# SAP PO JDBC SENDER CHANNEL ISSUE WITH QUERY WHICH CONTAINS VIEW

Tags: sap-pi

I have requirement to extract data (daily end of the day) from portal which have oracle database 11g.

They created one view given to me i.e. `Select * from "viewname"`.

I tried to execute this in query SQL statement in JDBC sender channel but it's not picking up showing an error a issue with `select * from "viewname"`.

Please anybody let me know what is the cause to this and another question if the view will update the next day that will pick old and new data that will cause an issue how can I avoid these?

Please help me to do this.

Regards,
Abdul

Comment: Could you provide us the related work you've done so far?

Comment: Please provide us full text of error from PIMON or RWB (the place you have got the error).

Comment: Hi Iliya Kuznetsov, the error is resolved but issue with JDBC sender channel i hava 500000 of historical data at database i need to pick up the all the rows to bw and they given a view name and they are not allowed to do the updation on there database i had put as a <test>.but i need to control the records from database flow how can i achieve this with out using update